# gcc stack memory allocation

Tags: c, gcc, gdb

I am confused a bit with the memory layout assignment
lets say we have:

```
int flag = 0;
char array[10];
```

In memory stack, the array is located above the flag.

```
(gdb) x/x array : 0xbffff4bc
(gdb) x/x flag :  0xbffff4cc
```

However, lets say we reversed the lines:

```
char array[10];
int flag = 0;
```

Still the assignment of memory is the same

```
(gdb) x/x array : 0xbffff4bc
(gdb) x/x flag :  0xbffff4cc
```

How come the assignment didn't change ? shouldn't the flag in the second option be above the array in the stack ? SO why is the memory being allocated to the array above the integer in the stack eventhough i am compiling with `-fno-stack-protector` flag ?
is that correct or not? 
i am running my code under gcc 4.7.2 Debian

**EDIT**

I just found a post of the same problem [memory-allocation-issue-buffer-overflow-attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15495167/gcc-memory-allocation-issue-buffer-overflow-attack)
However, when reading the first answer, in the comments it sates that when compiling with `-fno-stack-protector` should solve the problem (Allocate memory sequentially by order of declaration). It doesn't work in my case though. 
Any suggestions ?

Comment: The language does not make any guarantees about the relative memory locations of unrelated local variables. The compiler is free to rearrange these variables as it sees fit. All arrangements are "correct". Why do you find it strange? Your array has "uneven" size (10 bytes), so it is not surprising to see the compiler to move things around in order to pack and/or align them better.

Comment: i am basically trying to overflow the buffer and change the content of the flag, so when i have the flag above the buffer, that buffer overflow should not work.

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to?

Comment: because if the flag's memory is allocated before the buffer, the buffer will be above the flag in the stack. Hence when over flowing the buffer with a specific argument, the content in the flag's memory address will change. This will make it an different that zero and that's my goal. This works fine. However, when i reverse the order, i want to allocate memory to the array then to the integer in order to not allow that buffer over flow.

Comment: What if someone overflows it with a bunch of zeroes, and only starts monkeying around once they're getting to the bottom of the stack frame? It wouldn't change the value of `flag` at all, then.

Comment: @Paul, it will still work even if you try to overflow with a bunch of zeros. The actual value of the flag will change. PS i just tested it.

Comment: @T-D: OK, maybe I misunderstood "This will make it an different that zero and that's my goal".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing more testing and experimentation on this issue, a decent workaround would be use the   `-fstack-protector` to allow the compiler to place the buffer below the flag variable in memory in order to protect itself from a buffer overflow attack.

```
char password_buffer[16];
int auth_flag = 0;
```

so when you run it this way,

```
x/x password_buffer: 0xbffff4bc
x/x &auth_flag: 0xbffff4b8
```

That means that the `password_buffer` is assgneed memory below the `auth_flag`

Comment: Further reading: [Wikipedia: Buffer overflow protection → Stack-smashing protection → Implementations → GNU Compiler Collection (GCC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection#GNU_Compiler_Collection_.28GCC.29)

Comment: Thanks I look into that.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by the comment by @AndreyT, there is no requirement in the standard that says the compiler has to lay out local variables on the stack in the same order as they appear in the source, or for that matter in any particular order.

You can force them to be laid out sequentially by placing them in a struct, because the standard does specify layout rules for structs (C99 6.7.2.1 para 13). Even so the compiler is free to put padding between the elements if needed.

But either way your strategy is faulty, because the standard also says that writing outside the bounds of an array provokes "Undefined Behaivour", meaning that there is no guarantee that it will safely update your flag. Different architectures and/or compilers could respond differently, maybe causing hardware triggered exceptions or other fatal conditions. You cannot rely on any particular behaivour.

Comment: True, i am just experimenting with buffer overflow attacks for education reasons. I found in a book an example that says reversing those 2 lines would reverse their memory order in the stack. But i am guessing that's not true...

Answer (score 0):

It's quite normal (but in no way guaranteed, as @harmic pointed out) that larger sections are allocated first, to avoid memory fragmentation.

Comment: Can you add an evidence and relevant sources of what you claim to be "quite normal" avoidance of stack fragmentation?

Comment: No, because I no longer have access to compilers from the mid 1980:s and on.